# SystemRescueCd and Linux KVM

Tags: linux, debian, kvm-virtualization, debian-stretch, keyboard

I need to boot one KVM VM with [SystemRescueCD](https://www.system-rescue.org/). However, the keyboard doesn't work then... I tried adding USB keyboard in VM configuration, but that doesn't help. PS/2 keyboard in there cannot be removed for some reason, so I can't exclude this as the source of the problem.

```
% lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
Release:    9.13
Codename:   stretch
```

Comment: Well, what is the reason you can't shape your VM the way you need? Also, why do you want to boot it that way, probably there is a way to fix the *original* problem without booting it from a CD?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution... It's VM configuration problem of *display*, just like described here:https://askubuntu.com/questions/769108/xrdpxfce-to-install-virtual-machines-in-kvm-keyboard-does-not-work

Had to change Spice display to VNC display. Why should that impact operation of keyboard, really.